# Counting Records Over a Rolling Period of Time SQL (Based on Last Record)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm relatively new to SQL and trying to pull the following from an Oracle SQL database.

Let's say I have a table of users and the time that they logged in that looks like this:

Name        LOG_IN
Jim         13:00:05

Patrick     13:02:23

Steve       13:02:44

Emma        13:03:16

Steve       13:04:44

Jim         13:04:05

Jim         13:05:05

Jim         13:05:06

Patrick     13:05:17

Emma        13:05:18

Steve       13:08:13

Say I want to run a report which tells me their last user login in and all logins that happened within a timeframe of 5 minutes before the last login. If I was doing this in another language, I would just a for .. loop to get the last login and then count back to previous logins and compare if the login time falls within the 5 min window. I am unsure how I would accomplish the same thing with Oracle SQL. For example, for someone like Jim, his last login is at 13:05:06 so I would want all the times he logged in between 13:00:06 and 13:05:06, which would be:'

Name    LOG_IN

Jim     13:04:05

Jim     13:05:05

Jim     13:05:06

So the very first login (at 13:00:05) would not be included because it's not in the range.

The same report would return results for the other users as well, so for Steve, the following would be returned:

Name    LOG_IN

Steve   13:04:44

Steve   13:08:13

And the first login (at 13:02:44) would not be returned.

When I first looked at this, I thought the requirement was to pull all transactions within a 5 minute of the time of the report, but I have since learned I need to do this rolling period calculation based on last login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Name, LOG_IN
    from <table_name> A where LOG_IN >
    (select max(LOG_IN) from <table_name> where Name=A.Name)-(1/24./60.*5.);
```

Here's a sqlfiddle link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b231e/11/0
(don't know how long it will be persistent...)

Comment: Thanks so much - this works great! Another condition I wanted to add was to only return the people who have logged in at least 3 times in a 5 minute period, I updated your sqlfiddle to get this: select Name, Count(*) 
from bla A 
where LOG_IN > (select max(LOG_IN) from bla where Name=A.Name)-(1/24./60.*5.)
group by Name
having count(*) >= 3; and it works  - thanks again for your help!!